# (Rails) Uploading Directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I need to upload multiple files on my website.

But I need not just a form for uploading multiple files, I need to upload whole directories.

How's this possible for the minimalist?

Yours, Joern.

Comment: Just select all files from the dir. I think, you can't upload a whole directory, just files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to my somewhat limited knowledge this is not possible, only file transfer is possible, not directories.

Here are some workarounds, based on [discussion on Velocity Reviews](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t156265-upload-directory-from-browser-possible.html) and [another discussion](http://www.issociate.de/board/post/285214/):

- upload a zip, which you unzip at the server side
- upload directories over ftp (web page can be a front end to this)
- upload files one by one

I would go either for zip or ftp. Note: someone might have produced a gem that enables uploading directories (I know nothing of such thing, but I will be happy to find out, if there is).

Comment: thanks... I expected that there is no better way, sadly I see, I must accept this and find a workaround; I guess I'll solve it with zip files

Answer (score -2):

Adding another option to the list provided by Sorrow:

- upload via REST/JSON

OK, this is a partial solution, but it does give you the opportunity to write a script that reads your directory and POSTS to your website.