# How to upload a folder using Activestorage while maintaining original folder structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am looking for a way to upload whole folder using activestorage using its direct_upload feature but I am not able to retrieve file's relative path(webkitRelativePath) on rails end so that I can create exact same structure on S3 or on local disk.

Here the code I am using

```
 <%= form_tag('/action', method: "post", id:"myForm") do %>
  <%= file_field_tag(:file, webkitdirectory: '', directory: '', multiple: true, direct_upload: true) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit", id:"submit_btn") %>
<% end %>
```

Any help/suggestion greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about this? [Rails Uploading Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6747135/3733369)

Comment: This could be helpful too: [Multithreaded recursive directory uploader to S3 using fog.](https://github.com/chrishein/s3_uploader)

Comment: @Thrasher I am looking the solution in activestorage

Comment: Try a before_validation hook on the model: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75304634/457850