# How can I customize the path of a Rails 5.2 ActiveStorage attachment in Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

When adding attachments such as

```
has_one_attached :resume_attachment
```

saved files end up in the top level of the S3 bucket. How can I add them to subdirectories? For example, my old paperclip configuration could categorize in directories by model name.

Comment: Downvoters, please explain so I can improve the question. I haven't found a duplicate. If it is simply a bad idea please explain why.

Comment: Sadly you can't, I look for this too but I think AS is too "young" for the moment and there aren't all options that you can find in alternatives.

Comment: There are few questions nearly duplicates on SO about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852567/how-to-upload-a-folder-using-activestorage-while-maintaining-original-folder-str; I don't understand the downvoters as well :(

Comment: @codingaddicted thanks. Nearly duplicates, but none duplicate.

Comment: I totally agree, there are a lot specific aspects asked on SO that aren't covered by AS for the moment. For me you're question is 100% valid and I hope the AS team look at it and the other questions too.

Comment: Ha. The 6 downvote users were all removed. Some kind of mischief I suppose.

Comment: The power of karma ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not. There is only one option possible, at that time, for `has_one_attached`, `has_many_attached` macros that is `:dependent`.
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/macros.rb#L30

see (maybe the reason why you have downvotes, but it is about "direct" upload so...) : [How to specify a prefix when uploading to S3 using activestorage's direct upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389782/how-to-specify-a-prefix-when-uploading-to-s3-using-activestorages-direct-upload).
The response is from the main maintainer of Active Storage.

Comment: Thank you for finding a near but not duplicate. I'll update the title to constrain version and accept.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `before_validation` hook to set the desired key on S3 and the desired filename for the content disposition object properties on S3.

The `key` and `filename` properties on the attachment model make their way through to the ActiveStorage S3 gem and are converted into S3 key + content disposition object properties.

```rb
class MyCoolItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :preview_image
  has_one_attached :download_asset

  before_validation :set_correct_attachment_filenames

  def preview_image_path
    # This key has to be unique across all assets. Fingerprint it yourself.
    "/previews/#{item_id}/your/unique/path/on/s3.jpg"
  end

  def download_asset_path
    # This key has to be unique across all assets. Fingerprint it yourself.
    "/downloads/#{item_id}/your/unique/path/on/s3.jpg"
  end
  
  def download_asset_filename
    "my-friendly-filename-#{item_id}.jpg"
  end

  def set_correct_attachment_filenames
    # Set the location on S3 for new uploads:
    preview_image.key = preview_image_path if preview_image.new_record?
    download_asset.key = download_asset_path if download_asset.new_record?

    # Set the content disposition header of the object on S3:
    download_asset.filename = download_asset_filename if download_asset.new_record?
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this should work, but I don't have a present example to test it with. Have you tested the solution?